# Are redeclarations forbidden by C standard?

Tags: c, namespaces

C has no namespaces, but does it strictly forbid redeclarations, when compiler silently overrides some names by names from includes? Is it valid idea, that I can name my functions, structs, types whatever I want to, and rely on redeclaration compile-time error in case if name clashes?

For example, if I name my struct like `struct message` or whatever else widespread name, I don't want, that some dependency of dependency would break because of that, or on the contrary override my name.

Comment: Are you confusing _declaration_ and _definition_?

Comment: C very well has [name spaces](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.3).

Comment: If variable has tentative declaration in file scope then the previous declaration will be refered instead of overriding or whatsoever.

Comment: If you refer to change the type of an identifier, then yes, you will be warned.

Comment: @Olaf those are not the namespaces you are looking for.

Comment: @n.m.: **I** was actually not looking for anything. Not even for droids. Just commented on OP's assertion there are no name spaces in C, which is plain wrong (they are even name spaces in the C++ sense). C just has no **user-defineable** name spaces.

Comment: @Olaf and this helps to solve the problem how exactly?

Comment: @n.m.: Did I write an answer? No, I wrote a comment to clarify to OP. Especially as she asks about a `struct` with tag.

Answer (score 1):

> C has no namespaces

C has a some simple name spaces (not in the sense of C++):

It has different name space for identifiers: structure tag names, structure member names, label names, macro names...

```
struct a;
int a = 0;  // valid, different name space
```

You can have multiple external declarations:

```
extern int y;
extern int y;  // valid
```

With tentative definitions, you can have multiple declarations:

```
int z, z; // valid at file scope
```

You can have "benign redefinitions" of macros:

```
#define BLA 0
#define BLA 0  // valid
```

You are allowed to redeclare an identifier in different scopes:

```
{
    int x;
    {
        double x;  // valid
    }
}
```

In the same scope redeclaring an identifier is not valid and at least you'll get a diagnostic:

```
 int x = 0;
 double x = 0.0;  // not valid
```

If there are multiple definition of an object in different translation units, it is undefined behavior but the Standard not require a diagnostic so be careful because you may not get any warning.

Answer (score 1):

The content associated with a struct, union or enum tag can only be defined once in the same scope.  Also, the tag can be used in only one of struct, union or enum in that scope as they share the same namespace within that scope.

[N1570 ISO/IEC 9899:201x Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) §6.7.2.3 Tags

Answer (score 1):

**TL/DR Version** - You can only rely on the compiler catching name clashes for you when you have two different objects in the same scope with the same name, or when you try to use the same name for an enumeration constant and a function or object name, or when you try to use the same tag name for different `struct`, `union` and `enum` types, or when you try to use the same typedef name for different types.  Otherwise, your object declarations *may* "shadow" other object declarations/definitions in the includes.

**Edit** - See section 7.1.3 of the [C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for a description of identifiers reserved for use by the implementation.  Avoid using identifiers with leading underscores or a leading `to`, `is`, or `str`, and you should be reasonably safe, at least as far as the standard libraries are concerned.

**James Michener Version** - C has namespaces (see section 6.2.3 of the [C 2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), they're just not user-defineable:

- Label names
- `struct`, `union`, and `enum` tag names
- Members of structures or unions
- Everything else

Thus, the following code is legal:

```
void foo( void )                // ordinary identifier
{
  struct foo {                  // tag name, disambiguated by presence of struct keyword 
    int foo;                    // member name, disambiguated by struct declaration syntax
  } bar;
  ...
  bar.foo = ...;                // member name, disambiguated by . operator
  goto foo;                     // label name, disambiguated by goto
  ...
  foo: ...                      // label name, disambiguated by label syntax
}
```

Identifiers may "shadow" identifiers defined in an outer scope:

```
char *i;                   // file scope identifier
void blah( void )
{
  int i;                   // block scope identifier, "shadows" file scope i
  if ( some_condition() )
  {
    double i;              // block scope identifier, "shadows" outer block scope i
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Each of the above `i`s refers to a different object.

The same identifier can be used in different scopes:

```
void foo( void )
{
  int i;  // local to foo
  ...
}

void bar( void )
{
  int i;  // local to bar
  ...
}
```

In the case above, the identifier `i` is used for two different objects.

If an identifier has *external linkage*, then identifiers in different translation units can refer to the *same* object:

```
/**
 * foo.c
 */  
void foo( void )
{
  extern int blah;  // will resolve to the object defined in bar.c
  printf( "blah = %d\n", blah );
}

/**
 * bar.c
 */
int blah = 5;

void bar( void )
{
  foo();
}
```

What you *cannot* do is have two different objects in the same scope with the same identifier, or use an enumeration constant as a function or variable name, etc.:

```
void foo( void )
{
  enum bar { foo,   // illegal, clashes with identifier for function
             bar,
             bletch };
  enum bar bar;     // illegal, object name clashes with enumeration constant bar
  int i;
  double i;  // illegal, clashes with previous object definition
  ...
}
```

Comment: I meant module namespaces

Comment: *"Everything else"* ordinary identifiers and macro names live in different name spaces, 6.2.3 introduces the name spaces for the identifiers.

Comment: @ouah - "Name space" doesn't apply to macros, since they're expanded before compilation.  6.2.3 does not mention macro names.

Comment: @JohnBode C says it "There is one name space for macro names" but it is somewhat strange there is no mention in 6.2.3 as macro names are identified as *identifiers* in 6.2.1p1.

Comment: @ouah: 6.2.1p1 also says, "Macro names and macro
parameters are not considered further here, because prior to the semantic phase of
program translation any occurrences of macro names in the source file are replaced by the
preprocessing token sequences that constitute their macro definitions."  It's simply *not possible* for a macro name to clash with any other kind of identifier, because that name is replaced after preprocessing (which will likely lead to other problems if you *do* use the same name for a macro and other identifier).

Answer (score 1):

To give you a more pragmatic answer: yes, names that you give to your types, `struct`, functions etc can easily clash with names that other libraries use. And there is no automatic feature that would magically repair that.

This is one of the severe weaknesses of the C programming language. The C library itself even reserves a lot of names and prefixes for its own use, and it is not always simple to know what names you can use safely or not. E.g if you'd include the `<string.h>` header file all names starting with `str` would be forbidden for your own application code, e.g something like `strip` wouldn't be allowed for you.

This is why packages that are supposed to be included into other code, usually use a nameprefix for all their names that are globally visible. E.g POSIX' threads use the prefix `pthread_`.